# Deleting all HKQuantitySamples

Tags: ios, healthkit

I want to delete all HKQuantitySamples that my app has saved in the Health App for a certain HKQuantityType, how would I do that?

I can see the function
deleteObject:withCompletion:
in the Apple Documentation, but I do not really understand how to use it. Can somebody show an example maybe?

EDIT: I now use the following code for deleting:

I have saved my food information as a HKCorrelation and set my Local Food ID in the Correlations metadata HKMetadataKeyExternalUUID key.

For deletion I am fetching all the HKCorrelation objects between startDate and endDate and then if one of these fetched objects matches the Local Food ID I am looking for: 
- I delete every object in that Correlation, 
- Followed by deleting the Correlation itself

```
HKCorrelationType *foodType = [HKObjectType correlationTypeForIdentifier:HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierFood];

NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate options:HKQueryOptionNone];

HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:foodType predicate:predicate limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit sortDescriptors:nil resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (!results) {
        NSLog(@"An error occured fetching the user's tracked food. In your app, try to handle this gracefully. The error was: %@.", error);

        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (HKCorrelation *foodCorrelation in results) {
            if([[foodCorrelation.metadata valueForKey:HKMetadataKeyExternalUUID] isEqualToString:food_id_I_want_to_delete]) {
                NSSet *objs = foodCorrelation.objects;
                for (HKQuantitySample *sample in objs) {
                    [self.healthStore deleteObject:sample withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                        if (success) {
                            NSLog(@"Success. delete sample");
                        }
                        else {
                            NSLog(@"delete: An error occured deleting the sample. In your app, try to handle this gracefully. The error was: %@.", error);
                        }
                    }];
                }

                [self.healthStore deleteObject:foodCorrelation withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                    if (success) {
                        NSLog(@"Success. delete %@", [foodCorrelation.metadata valueForKey:HKMetadataKeyExternalUUID]);
                    }
                    else {
                        NSLog(@"delete: An error occured deleting the Correlation. In your app, try to handle this gracefully. The error was: %@.", error);
                    }
                }];
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}];

[self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
```

Comment: Did you get any help with this. I tried to use the deleteObject:withComplete method but it returned an "Object not found" error even though I had saved the object earlier into HealthKit using the saveObject

Comment: @sim I have updated my question with my solution